# Problem with the displaying of last question

Tags: javascript

In this code i have a problem with the last question. When i get to it the button that generate next answers is there but doesn't generate the answers

This code should generate questions with each of them showing 3 answers represented by 3 paragraphs and there is a button for showing the next answer and a button that generate the next question

```
    var qa = [
      {
        question: "What is HTML?",
        answer: ["HTML ", 
                "Its.",
                "HTd."]
      },
      {
        question: "What is JavaScript?",
        answer: ["JavaSe.", 
                "Its.", 
                "Jav."]
      },
      {
        question: "What is CSS?",
        answer: ["CSS .", 
        "I",
        "C."]
      }
    ];

    // Initialize variables to keep track of the current question and answer
    var currentQA = 0;
    var currentAnswer = 0;

    // Function to display the current question
    // Function to display the current question and hide the "next question" button
    function displayQuestion() {
      document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = qa[currentQA].question;
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "";
      currentAnswer = 0;
      document.getElementById("nextQuestion").style.display = "none"; // hide the "next question" button
      document.getElementById("next").style.display = "block"; // show the "next answer" button
      currentQA++; 
    }

    // Function to display the next answer or move to the next question
    function displayNext() {
      if (currentAnswer < qa[currentQA].answer.length) {
        // Display the next answer
        var answerElement = document.createElement("p");  // create a new paragraph element
        answerElement.textContent = qa[currentQA].answer[currentAnswer];  // set its text content to the answer
        answerElement.classList.add("answer-paragraph");  // add the desired class
        document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answerElement);
        currentAnswer++;
        if (currentAnswer == qa[currentQA].answer.length) {
          // Show the "next question" button when there are no more answers for this question
          document.getElementById("next").style.display = "none"; // hide the "next answer" button
          document.getElementById("nextQuestion").style.display = "block"; // show the "next question" button
        }
      } 
      else {
        // Move to the next question or show the quiz complete message
        currentQA++;
        if (currentQA == qa.length) {
          alert("Quiz complete!");
        } else {
          displayQuestion();
        }
      }
    }

    // Attach event listener to buttons
    document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", displayNext);
    document.getElementById("nextQuestion").addEventListener("click", displayQuestion);

    // Start by displaying the first question
    displayQuestion();
```

I tried to change the condition in if statements adding or substracting one but didn't work

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here? I don't understand this. You are showing answers of next question under current question?

Comment: Yes. It is more like a learning page that i am trying to create and that's why i want it to be this way. Also i discovered what was the real problem of the code. The last question doesn't display it's answers because every question somehow get the answers from the next. And still i haven't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood your problem correctly. but are you looking for something like this?

What i did here is displayed question and answer one by one when Next button is clicked. As soon as answers are finished we display Next Question button and then new question is appeared.

```js
var qa = [{
    question: "What is HTML?",
    answer: ["HTML ",
      "Its.",
      "HTd."
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What is JavaScript?",
    answer: ["JavaSe.",
      "Its.",
      "Jav."
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What is CSS?",
    answer: ["CSS .",
      "I",
      "C."
    ]
  }
];

// Initialize variables to keep track of the current question and answer
var currentQA = 0;
var currentAnswer = 0;

// Function to display the current question
// Function to display the current question and hide the "next question" button
function displayQuestion() {
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = qa[currentQA].question;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "";  
  document.getElementById("nextQuestion").style.display = "none"; // hide the "next question" button
  document.getElementById("next").style.display = "block"; // show the "next answer" button
  currentAnswer = 0;
}

// Function to display the next answer or move to the next question
function displayNext() {
  if (currentAnswer < qa[currentQA].answer.length) {
    // Display the next answer
    var answerElement = document.createElement("p"); // create a new paragraph element
    answerElement.textContent = qa[currentQA].answer[currentAnswer]; // set its text content to the answer
    answerElement.classList.add("answer-paragraph"); // add the desired class
    document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answerElement);
    currentAnswer++;
    if (currentAnswer == qa[currentQA].answer.length) {
      // Show the "next question" button when there are no more answers for this question
      document.getElementById("next").style.display = "none"; // hide the "next answer" button
      document.getElementById("nextQuestion").style.display = "block"; // show the "next question" button
      currentQA++;
      
      if (currentQA == qa.length) {
        setTimeout(() => alert("Quiz complete!"), 0);
        document.getElementById("nextQuestion").style.display = "none"; // hide the next question button as there are no more questions left
      }
    }
  }
}

// Attach event listener to buttons
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", displayNext);
document.getElementById("nextQuestion").addEventListener("click", displayQuestion);

// Start by displaying the first question
displayQuestion();
```

```html
<div id="question"></div>
<div id="answer"></div>
<button id="nextQuestion">Next Question</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

You can take this forward as alter as per your requirement.
Hope this helps.